# How to set a constant density model in STK'S Astrogator

Tags: atmospheric-drag, stk-agi, tools

I'm trying to verify a simplifying orbit maintenance strategy obtained from one of my numerical tools using Astrogator as a propagator.

My tool uses a constant density value obtained by averaging the values calculated with the Jacchia Bowman 2008 model. I would like to align this model in such a way that Astrogator also always uses this constant value.

I tried to set constant values (F10, F81, M10, M81, etc.) but the density value does not remain constant over time.
Is there a way, even by changing the atmosphere model in the Astrogator component browser, to always have the density value I want for the entire propagation time?

I realize that it is not realistic from the point of view of orbital dynamics but I need it for educational purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a constant density over a whole circular orbit, or also a constant density regardless of the altitude (for highly elliptical orbits e.g.)? For constant altitude you could try "Harris-Priester" as a atmospheric model. (And I won't comment on the STK EULA, forbidding using STK to verify own tools ;-) )

Comment: Hi, I need a constant density regardless of the altitude and I've already tried with Harris-Priester but the result was almost the same of JB 2008. To be more precise, I want to verify the "goodness" of Vallado's 72 algohoritm which loads a constant density value in its equations. Therefore I'm not validating a personal tool but just the equations behind this Maintenance strategy.